# Class Not Found Exception org//h2//Driver

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-properties

I am learning Spring Framework and trying to inject properties from the .properties file.

This is my .properties file

```
sprint.datasource.username=hamnghi
sprint.datasource.password=hamnghi
sprint.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test;
sprint.datasource.driver=org.h2.Driver;
```

When I tried to pass the `driver` field into the `Class.forName(drive)`, the program could not connect to the
database and threw a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/h2/Driver;` but it printed the `driver` variable as "org.h2.Driver" to the console just fine.
[My console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7lh9.png)

I also ran the program with `Class.forName("org.h2.Driver")`, and it ran fine; however, when I replaced it with the `driver`, it didn't work

This is my class.

```
package H2Database.db_connection;

import H2Database.functionality.Logging;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class H2Connection {
    private final static Logger logger = Logging.getLogger();

    @Value("${sprint.datasource.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${sprint.datasource.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${sprint.datasource.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${sprint.datasource.driver}")
    private  String driver;

    public Connection open(){
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            return connection;
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "H2Connection{" +
                "url='" + url + '\'' +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", driver='" + driver + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this all when Boot does it for you? Furthermore, you seem to be following a tutorial that is _more than 14 years old_, because the `Class.forName` has not been required since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED
You have trailing `;` in your config. remove it

The exception means the specific class is not found in the classpath.

You need to add the dependency contains the corresponding implemenation for h2:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, the program runs fine when I use `Class.forName("org.h2.Driver")`, but when I replace it with `driver`, it fails. Besides, I also added the dependency you suggest in the pom.xml file, but it still not working.

Comment: You have trailing ; in your config. remove it

Comment: Thank you so much. It was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You should complete the following steps to Configure the **H2** database to your Spring MVC application.

> Step 1: Add the following dependency in the pom.xml file
>
> ```
> <dependency>  
>     <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>  
>     <artifactId>h2</artifactId>  
>     <scope>runtime</scope>  
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> Step 2: configure these properties in the application.properties file.
>
> ```
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb  
> spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver  
> spring.datasource.username=sa  
> spring.datasource.password=  
> spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
> ```
>
> **Note:** Spring MVC does not auto configure the properties of the
> application.properties. You should configure it using configuration
> class.
>
> Step 3: Configure the Database.
>
> ```
> @Configuration
> @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
> public class DataSourceConfig {
>
>     @Value("${sprint.datasource.url}")
>     private String url;
>
>     @Value("${sprint.datasource.username}")
>     private String username;
>
>     @Value("${sprint.datasource.password}")
>     private String password;
>
>     @Value("${sprint.datasource.driver}")
>     private  String driver;
>
>     @Bean
>     public DataSource testDataSource() {
>         BasicDataSource bds = new BasicDataSource();
>         bds.setDriverClassName(driver);
>         bds.setUrl(url);
>         bds.setUsername(username);
>         bds.setPassword(password);
>         return bds;
>     }
> }
> ```